# Independence of binary variables

Tags: independence

I'm performing a study and I have the following table, where each binary column means a given attempt of communication in a given time:

Device 1: 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
Device 2: 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
Device 3: 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
Device n: 1 1 1 1 0 1 0

Typically, I have a set o devices that perform a given attempt of communication at the same time. When the outcome of this attempt is 1 it means that a link was established and 0 otherwise.

I'd like to perform a statistical analysis that proves that a failure of communication (0) doesn't affect all devices equally. For instance, a given device doesn't establish communication, but this doesn't mean that all devices will fail together in a given attempt.

From my probability classes some years ago, I remember that we can check if some variables are independent using:

(A $\cap$ B $\cap$ C) = P(A).P(B).P(C), where A is the probability of communication failure for Device 1, B for Device 2 and C for device n. 
Does it make sense this independence checking? What statistical test should I use for this particular study?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "affecting all devices equally"? On the face of it, I would have thought that your table already proves that a failure of communication doesn't affect all devices equally, since otherwise all columns would have to be either all $0$s or all $1$s, no?